# a Python module that adds "Places" and/or "Devices" to a Tkinter filedialog?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, filedialog

Is there a distributed Python gui module that adds "Places" and/or "Devices" to tkinter's filedialog?  For example, when I open a file manager, like Dolphin for KDE desktops, the file manager has a left side bar with special "Places" and other attached "Devices" (filedialog just displays the contents of one drive).  I'd like to know where to find the module, or a pointer on how to go about adding the code to filedialog if I need to create it myself.